# How To Obtain An Annotation Of A Function Literal At Runtime

Tags: kotlin, reflection, annotations, function-literal, kotlin-function-type

```
package _z_additional

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberFunctions
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.reflect

/*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439469/how-to-obtain-an-annotation-of-a-function-literal-at-runtime*/
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
object _13_Reflection_ObtainingAnnotationOfAFunctionLiteral_Test {

    @Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
    private annotation class A

    //@formatter:off
    @A private fun f1() {}
    private val f2: () -> Unit = @A {}
    private val f3: () -> Unit = @A fun() {}
    //@formatter:on

    @Test
    fun demonstrate_usingReflect() {
        listOf(::f1, f2.reflect(), f3.reflect()).filterNotNull().withIndex().forEach { (index, f) ->
            println("[$index] Function name = ${f.name}")
            println("[$index] Annotations = ${f.annotations.joinToString()}")
            println()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun demonstrate_usingClass() {
        listOf(f2::class, f3::class).withIndex().forEach { (index, cls) ->
            val invokeFunction: KFunction<*> = cls.declaredMemberFunctions.first {it.name == "invoke" && it.isOperator}
            println("[$index] Function name = ${invokeFunction.name}")
            println("[$index] Annotations = ${invokeFunction.annotations.joinToString()}")
            println()
        }
    }

}
```

`demonstrate_usingReflect` Output

> [0] Function name = f1
> [0] Annotations = @_z_additional._13_Reflection_ObtainingAnnotationOfAFunctionLiteral_Test$A()
>
> [1] Function name = 
> [1] Annotations =
>
> [2] Function name = 
> [2] Annotations =

`demonstrate_usingClass` Error Output

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class is an internal synthetic class generated by the Kotlin compiler, such as an anonymous class for a lambda, a SAM wrapper, a callable reference, etc. It's not a Kotlin class or interface, so the reflection library has no idea what declarations does it have. Please use Java reflection to inspect this class: class _z_additional._13_Reflection_ObtainingAnnotationOfAFunctionLiteral_Test$f2$1